# Iterators over two-dimensional vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a function that will remove the duplicates in an unsorted vector, keeping it unsorted:

```
int unsortedRemoveDuplicates(std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
std::set<int> seenNums; //log(n) existence check

auto itr = begin(numbers);
while(itr != end(numbers))
{
    if(seenNums.find(*itr) != end(seenNums)) //seen? erase it
        itr = numbers.erase(itr); //itr now points to next element
    else
    {
        seenNums.insert(*itr);
        itr++;
    }
}

    return seenNums.size();
}
```

However I wish to use this for a two-dimensional vector initialised as

```
vector<vector<int>> numbers;
```

and have the function remove duplicates from only one row determined by a row number passed into the function.

I've tried changing the iterator itr to

```
auto itr = begin(numbers[row]);
while(itr != end(numbers[row]))....
```

where row is pass into the function, but this only creates a seg fault, and so I'm stuck here getting it to iterate over one row. Any suggestions?

Comment: `numbers.[row]` Why the `.`? did you mean `numbers[row]`?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, edited

Answer (score 1):

Don't over think. Just iterate the outer vector and pass each inner vector to the function.

```
for (auto& each_row : numbers)
    unsortedRemoveDuplicates(each_row);
```

Comment: Thanks Nicky. I'm looking at passing in just one specific row without running over every row, what would that look like?

Comment: `unsortedRemoveDuplicates(numbers[0]);`, `unsortedRemoveDuplicates(numbers[1]);`, etc